# Sobrepondo div's

Tags: html5, css3, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma tela que quando clicado no botão ela anda "x" px, o problema e quando ela faz esse efeito, tenho que mandar a tela que esta embaixo aparecer, o que acontece e que as letras da tela de baixo sobrepõe a tela de cima.
usei o z-index funcionou, mais todos meus links da tela de baixo pararam de funcionar.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <!-- TELA DE APRESENTAÇÃO INICIAL -->
    <div class="container1">
        <div class="left" id="content2"><img src="img/logo.png" class=""></div>
        <div class="right" id="content">
            <!-- BOX SERVIÇOS -->
            <div class="box hover-zoomin">
                <a id="animate" class="box-1 btn-toggle" data-element="#minhaDiv">
                    <img src="img/service.jpg" class="box-1">
                    <div class="titulo">
                        <i class="fas fa-briefcase pos-icone"></i>
                        <h1 class="pos-titulo">Serviços</h1>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- BOX PORTIFOLIO -->
            <div class="box hover-zoomin">
                <a href="" class="box-1" id="animate2">
                    <img src="img/portfolio.jpg" class="box-1">
                    <div class="titulo">
                        <i class="fas fa-handshake pos-icone"></i>
                        <h1 class="pos-titulo">Sobre nós</h1>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- BOX CONTATOS -->
            <div class="box hover-zoomin">
                <a href="" class="box-1" id="animate3">
                    <img src="img/contact.jpg" class="box-1">
                    <div class="titulo">
                        <i class="fas fa-phone pos-icone"></i>
                        <h1 class="pos-titulo">Contatos</h1>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- BOX SOBRE -->
            <div class="box hover-zoomin">
                <a href="" class="box-1" id="animate4">
                    <img src="img/about.jpg" class="box-1">
                    <div class="titulo">
                        <i class="fas fa-star pos-icone"></i>
                        <h1 class="pos-titulo">Portifolio</h1>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- FINAL DA TELA DE APRESENTAÇÃO -->

    <!-- TELA DE SERVIÇOS -->
    <div class="container-fluid" id="minhaDiv" style="opacity: 0; display: none;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2 img-servico d-none d-lg-block">
                <a href="#" id="fechar"><i class="fas fa-times fa-2x icone-close"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 my-4">
                        <h1 class="text-center display-4">AQUI VAI O <span class="text-danger">TITULO</span></h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row pad justify-content-center">
                    <!-- <div class="text-center"> -->
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 text-center">
                        <!-- IMAGEM DO VIDEO -->
                        <img src="img/infinity.jpg" class="rounded" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                        <!-- ICONE DO VIDEO -->
                        <a class="venobox" data-autoplay="true" data-vbtype="video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6-WUWmV-fg" style="position: absolute; top: 40%; right: 43%;"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-4x cor-icone"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
                        <h4 class=""><strong>TITULO</strong></h4>
                        <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p>
                    </div>
                    <!-- </div> -->
                </div>

                <div class="row pad my-5">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                        <div class="card border border-danger py-5 px-3 text-center">
                            <img src="img/1.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; width: 30%;">
                            <img src="img/ideia.png" class="mx-auto" style="width: 70px;">
                            <!-- <i class="far fa-user text-center m-5  p-5 fa-3x rounded " style="background-color: red; color: white;"></i> -->
                            <p class="text-center mt-5"><strong>USUARIOS 1250</strong></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                        <div class="card border border-danger py-5 px-3 text-center">
                            <img src="img/1.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; width: 30%;">
                            <img src="img/ideia.png" class="mx-auto" style="width: 70px;">
                            <!-- <i class="far fa-user text-center m-5  p-5 fa-3x rounded " style="background-color: red; color: white;"></i> -->
                            <p class="text-center mt-5"><strong>USUARIOS 1250</strong></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
                        <div class="card border border-danger py-5 px-3 text-center">
                            <img src="img/1.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; width: 30%;">
                            <img src="img/ideia.png" class="mx-auto" style="width: 70px;">
                            <!-- <i class="far fa-user text-center m-5  p-5 fa-3x rounded " style="background-color: red; color: white;"></i> -->
                            <p class="text-center mt-5"><strong>USUARIOS 1250</strong></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <h1 class="text-center display-4">TITULO</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <img src="img/usuario1.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" width="140px;">
                                    <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <img src="img/usuario1.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" width="140px;">
                                    <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <img src="img/usuario1.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" width="140px;">
                                    <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <img src="img/usuario1.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" width="140px;">
                                    <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <img src="img/usuario1.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" width="140px;">
                                    <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <img src="img/usuario1.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" width="140px;">
                                    <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <img src="img/usuario1.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" width="140px;">
                                    <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="text-center">
                                    <img src="img/usuario1.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-circle" width="140px;">
                                    <h5>Lorem ipsum</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row  my-5">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <h1 class="display-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h1>
                            <p class="text-muted">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary p-3">Conheça mais</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 img-footer">
                        <p class="py-3 text-white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

/* =================== FONTE PARA TITULOS =================== */
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5{
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

/*=================== CONTAINER 1 ======================================*/
/*CONTAINER DA 1° TELA*/
.container1{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*z-index: 100;*/
}

.left {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white;
}
.right {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.box-1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/*=================== IMAGEM DE FUNDO =================== */
.img-servico{
    background-image: url(img/service.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
    height: auto;
}

.img-servico:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
/*=================== IMAGEM DE FUNDO DO VIDEO ===================*/
.img-video{
    background-image: url(img/infinity.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: auto;
}

/*=================== IMAGEM DE FUNDO DO CARD*/
.img-card{
    background-image: url(img/1.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
}

/* IMAGEM DE FUNDO DO CARD 2 ===================*/
.img-card-2{
    background-image: url(img/2.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
}

/*IMAGEM DE FUNDO CARD 3 ===================*/
.img-footer{
    background-image: url(img/service.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center top;
}

/*=================== QUEBRA DE LINHA ===================*/
@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .container1 {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .left, .right {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .left{
        height: 40%;
    }
    .right{
        height: 60%;
    }
    .left-2{
        display: none;
    }
    .pad{
        padding-right: 0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
}

/* ================================== EFEITO DE ZOOM ==============================*/
/*ZoomIn Hover Effect*/
.hover-zoomin a {
    /*display: block;*/
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hover-zoomin img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.hover-zoomin:hover img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
/* ================================== FINAL EFEITO DE ZOOM ==============================*/

/* ====================================== CONFIGURAÇÃO DO ICONE ======================*/
.titulo{
    position: absolute;
}

.pos-titulo{
    color: white;
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.pos-icone{
    color: white;
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin-left: 65px;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
}
/* ====================================== FINAL DA CONFIGURAÇÃO DO ICONE ======================*/

/* ====================================== MARGEM DO BOTÃO FECHAR ======================*/
.close{
    margin: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.close:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* ====================================== FINAL MARGEM DO BOTÃO ======================*/

/* ====================================== ESPAÇAMENTO DA PAGINA PRINCIPAL /* ======================================*/
.pad{
    padding-left: 3rem;
    padding-right: 3rem;
}

/*====================================== ESCONDE A TELA ======================================*/
.sumir{
    display: none;
}

/*====================================== COR DO ICONE DO VIDEO ======================================*/
.cor-icone{
    color: #F33F3F;
}

.cor-icone:hover{
    color:  red;
}
/* ===================================== CONFIGURAÇÃO DO ICONE DE FECHAR ============================*/
.icone-close{
    position: absolute; 
    left: 80%;
    top: 10px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.icone-close:hover{
    color: white;
}
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#animate").click(function() {
            $('#content').animate({
                "left": "100%"
            }, 1500);
            $('#content2').animate({
                "right": "100%"
            }, 1500);
            $('#minhaDiv').animate({
                "opacity": "1"
            }, 1000);

        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#fechar").click(function() {
            $('#content').animate({
                "left": "0%"
            }, 1500);
            $('#content2').animate({
                "right": "0%"
            }, 1500);
            $('#minhaDiv').animate({
                "opacity": "0"
            }, 1000);
            $('#minhaDiv').addClass("sumir");
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- APARECER TELA DE BAIXO -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".btn-toggle").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            el = $(this).data('element');
            $(el).toggle();
        });
    });
</script>

<!-- INICIALIZAÇÃO DO PLUGIN - MODAL VIDEO(VENOBOX) -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.venobox').venobox();
        `insira o código aqui`
    });

    $("#firstlink").venobox().trigger('click');
</script>
```

Comment: Tem como colocar somente os trechos de código envolvidos e sem imagens para ficar melhor de analisar?

Comment: Onde vc colocou o z-index que funcionou?

Comment: coloquei o z-index na classe container1

Comment: "os links" que vc se refere são as 4 imagens, duas em cima e duas embaixo?

Comment: isso, na verdade só esta funcionando o link que esta escrito "serviços", quando clico nessa imagem, a tela se divide e aparece a tela de baixo, e como disse ela sobrepoe a de cima.

Comment: Na verdade não está sobrepondo não. Ao clicar, a tela sobe e os links são animados para fora da tela.

Comment: mais enquanto os links(imagens) estão saindo da tela, você reparou que a tela debaixo aparece sobre a de cima.

Comment: Não consegui reparar não. A única coisa que vejo são as imagens que estavam lá saindo pelas laterais da tela rs

Comment: Acho que vc teria que colocar um print da tela antes e depois.

Comment: cara consegui aqui, coloquei o z-index na classe left e right, agora nao sobrepoe e os links debaixo continua funcionando.

Comment: Não sei se entendi, mas coloque z-index em tudo que quer que apareça por cima. Pra garantir, usa um !important =S